# Scaled coeficients in mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm running a mixed model with two continuous predictor variables, using lme4. I got the following error:

> Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue - Rescale variables?

When exploring the data, the problem I saw was that there were different scales (x1 were numbers less than 0, x2 were whole numbers greater than 20). So I scaled the variables, and the problem was over. However, I would like to know how to interpret the regression coefficients. I understand that with scaled variables, it's necessary to divide the coefficient between the sd of the selected variable, to be able to interpret them as usual. So I have these questions:

1. It's correct to use this in a mixed model (for individual level coefficients, I think))?
2. How can I do it in R?
3. Can the `coef()` function be used on a single variable to do this procedure, one by one? or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- yes, scaling of regression coefficients works the same way in any linear-type model (linear models, linear mixed models, GLMs, GLMMs, ...)
- if the log-likelihoods of the two fits are nearly identical (say, within 0.001 units of each other), then it's probably the case that the warning about the very large eigenvalue is a false alarm, and you can go ahead and interpret the unscaled model without worry. (If the large difference in scaling were actually causing numerical problems it's unlikely that the original model would fit just as well as the model with scaled coefficients.)
- there are a variety of posts on Stack Overflow that give R solutions for retrieving unscaled coefficients from the scaled fit: e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642111/how-to-unscale-the-coefficients-from-an-lmer-model-fitted-with-a-scaled-respon/23643740), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324971/back-transform-coefficients-from-glmer-with-scaled-independent-variables-for-pre/53735644#53735644), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268031/unscale-and-uncenter-glmer-parameters?rq=1) ...